# 2018 Elantra EPS steering wheel noise

Tags: hyundai, steering, power-steering

I have recently noticed a whining noise coming from the steering wheel of my 2018 Elantra. I'm not sure what's causing the noise, and it usually occurs while driving at low speed, especially while parking. The car drives and steers perfectly, and the EPS warning light is not displayed. Please keep in mind that the car has no power steering fluid, since it is an Electric Power Steering system. I never noticed this sound before, and it started in the summer months, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. If anyone has any knowledge on what this noise could be, please let me know.

Thank You!

Comment: Is it under warranty? If so, take it to the dealership for a warranty repair.